# Rendering data output from database to Highcharts using JSON

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, highcharts, pie-chart

I have an SQL query that returns output similar to the following:

| Project id | Completed | In Progress | Not Started |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |

How can I loop this data returned from SQL in C# and provide it to Highcharts using JSON format?

Specifically, I want to use variable radius pie, link: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/variable-radius-pie-chart.

I want to calculate the percentage of completeness of all projects and present them in the pie.

Important: I want the chart to dynamically be generated depending on any number of records returned. I don't want to specify the projects by myself in the JSON data series, It must be taken from an array.

SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS projects;
CREATE TABLE projects(id int primary key, column1 varchar(20),column2 varchar(20),column3 varchar(20));

INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 1,'Completed','Not Started','Completed');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 2,'Completed','Not Started','Completed');
INSERT INTO projects VALUES( 3,'Completed','Not Started','In Progress');


select 
   id, 
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,9)='Completed' THEN 1 END) as 'Competed',
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,11)='In Progress' THEN 1 END) as 'In Progress',
   count(CASE WHEN left(c,11)='Not Started' THEN 1 END) as 'Not Started'
from (
   SELECT id,Column1 as C from  projects
   union all
   SELECT id,Column2 from  projects
   union all 
   SELECT id,Column3 from  projects
   ) x
group by id;
```

Json:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'variablepie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Countries compared by population density and total area.'
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> {point.name}</b><br/>' +
      'Area (square km): <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' +
      'Population density (people per square km): <b>{point.z}</b><br/>'
  },
  series: [{
    minPointSize: 10,
    innerSize: '20%',
    zMin: 0,
    name: 'countries',
    data: [{
      name: 'Spain',
      y: 505370,
      z: 92.9
    }, {
      name: 'France',
      y: 551500,
      z: 118.7
    }, {
      name: 'Poland',
      y: 312685,
      z: 124.6
    }, {
      name: 'Czech Republic',
      y: 78867,
      z: 137.5
    }, {
      name: 'Italy',
      y: 301340,
      z: 201.8
    }, {
      name: 'Switzerland',
      y: 41277,
      z: 214.5
    }, {
      name: 'Germany',
      y: 357022,
      z: 235.6
    }]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the SQL and also an output of the JSON data?

Comment: I just added them. Thank you !

Comment: Your expected json doesn't match the SQL. With your SQL how do you calculate the `y` & `z`?

Comment: Actually ignore that issue I will fix it later. Imagine that I want only to calculate the completed as y. I will change the chart type into normal Pie chart that takes only y values ( completed ).

Comment: It's not a JSON, it's a JavaScript config to render the Highcharts chart. Just the expected data should be in the JSON format, parsed and added to the chart. In the API you can find what data format Highcharts expect to render variable-pie chart: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.variablepie.data